# android bluetooth printer connection?

Tags: android, bluetooth

i had J2ME application to print data byte to printer.
But now, i have to convert that code to android code.

My problem is : 
i can't send data byte[] to mobile printer from my device Galaxy Tab Froyo via bluetooth?

here my simple code :

```
UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
BluetoothSocket btSocket btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
btSocket.connect();
OutputStream outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
String message = "this is message";
byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();
outStream.write(msgBuffer.length);
outStream.write(msgBuffer);
```

when i see the LogCat, it show that i through all that process with no error.

can anyone help me?

thanks in advance,

aql

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to my mind is `outStream.close()` that you forgot to write. Though I am most probably wrong

Comment: Yeh I wondered that too.  The printer will likely wait for a full page worth's of data (or a form-feed), or the end of the data before it starts printing.

Comment: Have you tried to use [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)? 
Like `BufferedWrited writer = new BufferedWriter(outStream, SIZE);`. Then experiment with different buffer SIZE values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the printer what you are going to print(text, img, barcode). All bluetooth printer use the sam ehexadecimal codes to handle that. Try:

```
        byte[] arrayOfByte1 = { 27, 33, 0 }; //This defines the FontType we use 2 in the next line for 0 thats the default Font.
        byte[] printformat = { 0x1B, 0x21,(byte)(0x8|arrayOfByte1[2]) }; 

        btoutputstream = btsocket.getOutputStream();

        btoutputstream.write(printformat);
        btoutputstream.write(printAlign);
        btoutputstream.write(message.getBytes());
```